# Can a secondary 'From' address be specified in AcrobatDC/javascript

Tags: javascript, acrobat

I have a simple javascript (using Action Wizard) that sends the currently opened .pdf to specified recipients via MS Outlook.

I can customize the "To, CC, Subject, body" fields, no problem.

But I have 2 different email accounts, one is personal and the other is a corporate group mailbox.

I would like that email to come from that second "From" address. Similar to the ".SentOnBehalfOfName" VBA command.

Is there a way to do this?